# Opening multiple Outlook Window Send Email with C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sendmail

I need to open several Outlook windows previously populated with ticulo and email body for later user to inform the senders. I need to open several windows (I walk a grid to know how many windows).
I'm trying to do this with threads but an error message occurs saying: Outlook can not do this because the dialog box is open. Please close it and try again "
How to open multiple competing windows?

**Test Call**

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int qtdEventos = dgvDescEvento.RowCount;
    Thread[] Threads = new Thread[qtdEventos];
    try
    {
        cEmail testeEmail = new cEmail();
        for (int i = 0; i < qtdEventos; i++)
        {
            Threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new cEmail().Monta));
        }
        foreach (Thread t in Threads)
        {
            t.Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace NavEventos.Class
{
    class cEmail
    {
        private Outlook.Application outlookApp;
        public cEmail()
        {
            outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
        }

        public void Monta()
        {
            string pTitulo = "Title";
            string pAssunto = "Body test";
            Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMailItem.GetInspector;

            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMailItem.Recipients;

            #region MONTA ASSUNTO
            oMailItem.Subject = pTitulo;
            #endregion

            #region MONTA CORPO DO E-MAIL
            oMailItem.Body = pAssunto;
            #endregion

            oMailItem.Display(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved this by using the "Lock" inside the method and call the thread normally. This opens only one window at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not like this... but you shouldn't try. ;(

As you can see the Outlook COM interface is trying very hard to prevent you from doing this, it is one of the limitations of the outlook automation libraries that displaying a mail item is done in a modal kind of way.

There is good reason for this, your user is in your LOB application, then your code wants them to read an email in outlook, which you have done using the COM automation libraries for outlook. Now their outlook icon in the toolbar is flashing because a new email modal window has opened up, but this dialog may have opened up behind your current LOB app.

Now the user will need to switch context into Outlook to see the dialog and read the email.

If you can review your need to open these emails all at the same time then you and outlook com automation will get along just fine :)

Otherwise consider writing a plugin for Outlook and moving your email management routines into outlook itself. In there you can be very creative, sounds like you really need just a master - detail style of interface, like the main outlook browser, so you have a list of these emails and as the user clicks on them they are displayed in the preview inspector.

> Maybe the solution is to use your logic to move these messages into a
>   specific folder in outlook, then use Outlook automation to make this
>   folder the current active window in outlook, then the user can decide
>   which emails they want to action or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Chris.